# php : maximum date from array

Tags: php, json

I need to read Maximum Date from array value with PHP. Can anyone suggest to how to get read this from JSON array?

**Here is my JSON array.** I retrieve data from URL like this.

```
$result = json_decode($result);
$data = $result->response->data;
foreach ($data as $datas => $value) {
  $checktime = $value->checktime;
  echo $checktime;
}
```

**Output :**

```
2018-03-29T08:57:33-04:002018-03-29T08:57:57-04:002018-03-31T09:49:20-04:002018-03-29T08:57:17-04:002018-03-31T09:49:23-04:002018-03-29T08:57:41-04:00
```

I need to get the max date here. How do I get this value?

Comment: Did you tryed covert the dates to strtotime and make a usort ?

Comment: `$result` is undefined in your code. Consider re-reading [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the current date is higher than the maximum, if it is then replace the maximim.

```
$max_date = '';
foreach ($data as $value) {
    if ($value->checktime > $max_date) {
        $max_date = $value->checktime;
    }
}
echo $max_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `strtotime()` to store the most recent like this

```
$mostRecent= 0;    
foreach ($data as $datas => $value) {
    $checktime = strtotime($value->checktime);
    if ($checktime > $mostRecent) {
    $mostRecent = $checktime;
    }
}
```